# Controlling Decimal Places in an Existing JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, decimal

I'm still a newbie to Java and netbeans. I'm a bit stuck on how I can control the decimal places in my existing JTable. I have searched for all I can but I can't seem to integrate the results I get into my existing JTable. I just want the 2nd and last column to control the decimal to 3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a TableCellRenderer. Start by having a look at [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: If you are overriding the `getValueAT()` method, you can return a string formatted using `DecimalFormat` as described here : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: I used the decimalFormat but not the custom renderers yet because it's still too complicated for me. I'll try it at a later time. for now, i'm just happy that it works. :) Thanks both!